# Arch Linux installation: This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU

Tags: linux, tar, archlinux

I want to install Arch Linux on my old HP Pavilion zv5000 (which should have a Pentium 4 CPU).

I was not sure about which version was right for me, between x86-64 and i686, so I chose the `archlinux-2017.03.01-dual.iso` file on the download page of one of the Arch Linux mirror sites (for example, [this mirror](https://archlinux.surlyjake.com/archlinux/iso/2017.03.01/)). I tried the "dual" version because I was not able to extract `archlinux-bootstrap-2017.03.01-i686.tar.gz` nor `archlinux-bootstrap-2017.03.01-x86_64.tar.gz`.

But now, after I burned the ISO image on a CD, booting from the live CD and trying to install Arch gives me:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

Why is it impossible to extract the `.tar.gz` files? I tried from two or three mirrors but trying to extract it with `tar xzf` gives me write permission errors.

Also, what is the "dual" ISO image really? Maybe my mistake was here.

[*] Yes, I am totally noob :)

Comment: A `P4` while having 64-bit capabilities is officially a `32-bit` processor. Burn the .iso, it will boot to an install menu and it will give you the choice to install either `64-bit` or `32-bit` versions of Arch (note: the `32-bit` version of Arch is going away in September `:(` (I still have i686 Arch installs) I would suggest installing the 32-bit on P4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Actually dual iso means you can choose either 64 or i86 when booting. And it was true until March 2017. Starting from March i686 version is not supported anymore.

When I downloaded iso of 2016 everything worked fine.